# Distance to median vs average intra-distances

Tags: geometry, median

Consider $n$ points in a vector space, denoted $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$. I am wondering if the following inequality holds true:
$$
\min_x \sum_{i=1}^n d(a_i, x) \leq \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} d(a_i, a_j)
$$
where $d(.,.)$ is a distance (or a pseudo-distance) and $x$ can be any distance in the vector space. I tried to prove it in various ways but could not succeed. I could check it works in some cases, so I would be glad to see if it works in **all** cases or to get a counterexample!

Comment: Is $x$ any vector in the vector space or is it one of the set $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$?  Also, what are the $s_j$ and $s_i$?  Should those be $a_i$, $a_j$?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it. Indeed, the $s_i$ are the $a_i$ and $x$ can be any vector in the space.